# How do I use an exported module in Angular1 using Webpack

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, webpack

I have the following coffeescript...

```
LogicThing = 
  doSomething: (obj) ->
    console.log(obj)
 ...
if module?
  module.exports =
    LogicThing : LogicThing
```

Then in another file I use this by

```
LogicThing.doSomething({name: object})
```

Then in my webpack I make sure it gets loaded first...

```
var files = glob.sync([
    './src/main/coffee/utilities/LogicThing.coffee',
    './src/main/coffee/**/*Module.coffee',
    './src/main/coffee/**/*.coffee'
]);
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/typescripts/polyfills.ts',
        vendor: './src/main/typescripts/vendor.ts',
        resources: './src/main/typescripts/resources.ts',
        app: files
    },
    ...
}
```

Problem is once I compile everything using webpack I get...

> ReferenceError: LogicThing is not defined

When I try to add it to the webpack like this...

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        ...
        LogicThing: 'LogicThing'
    }),
    ...
]
```

But then when I call webpack I get...

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'LogicThing' in

How do I handle this situation?

**FYI**

```
"coffee-script": "^1.10.0",
```

**Update**

Per comments I tried adding this to the other file...

```
require("../LogicThing")
```

To the top of my file but I still get...

> ReferenceError: LogicThing is not defined

Comment: Do you export and import the `LogicThing`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, as for export I thought I included that code. the `module.export` stuff. As for import I am not sure, previously it was a global variable so I would assume nothing had to import it.

Comment: You need to do something like `export LogicThing` and then in the file you use it, `import LogicThing from "./LogicThing"` for example

Comment: `import` is an ES2015 keyword so I don't think I can use it in straight Coffeescript (IE no ES2015 shim) right?

Comment: Also import is a coffeescript keyword along with ES2015 https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3162

Comment: What about `const LogicThing = require("../LogicThing")`?

Comment: Still didn't work :-/